# Python: PanelOLS - two-way clustering?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

In Python/Pandas I use the PanelOLS function. This function gives you the ability to cluster your standard errors. For instance:

```
PanelOLS(y=panel.Y, x=panel[['X1', 'X2'], nw_lags=10, time_effects=True,
         cluster='time')
```

But I would like to also cluster by standard errors by `entity` as well as in `time`.

Is there a way to do so? If not, what about the panel function in `statsmodel`? I have a hard time to find the documentation on Panel regression using statsmodel.

**UPDATE**
If I control using the newey-west lags (`nw_lags`) , isn't this like `cluster='entity'`? So, if I use both `nw_lags` and `cluster=time`, it is like doing a 2-way clustering?

Comment: No, Newey-West isn't the same thing as clustering by time. You'll probably have more luck asking your question on the statsmodels group at https://groups.google.com/group/pystatsmodels?hl=en

Comment: Wow! Heavy duty econometrics in Python? For extensive modelling, I would defer to R as a strong statistician community readily contributes. Plus, it too is open-source. This might be a Stats Exchange question and I may be wrong but two-way clustering is a newer concept for cluster-robust SEs and I would bet the house R like in [plm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) would have a package than Python. But consider grouping `entity` and `time` as new variable, then run that as the cluster.

Comment: @Parfait What's that supposed to mean? Here is the list of available heteroscedasticity or correlation robust covariance matrices http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.get_robustcov_results.html which includes one way and two way cluster robust and two kinds of panel-HAC sandwiches. However, statsmodels doesn't have the traditional econometrics panel data models yet. (Fixed effects can be created with a categorical variable in the formula. Random Effects for linear models could be estimated with a linear mixed effects model.)

Comment: I am actually thinking to simply run a OLS using Driscoll-Kraay standard errors (cluster on time and entity) outside of the Panel OLS framework of Pandas and then use time dummies to control time seasonality instead

Comment: see recent mailing list thread for use of Driscoll-Kraay https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/Cs-2mlC3C8g/kWUxPZK_JQAJ  Error in docstring, and fragility to input specification.

Answer (score 0):

In Thompson (2011) "Simple Formulas for standard errors that cluster by both frim and time" he describes how you can achieve double-clustering with commands that allow only one way clustering.

Denote your variance estimator clustered by entity by `V_ent` and your variance estimator clustered by time by `V_time` and the heteroskedasticity-robust estimator by `V_white`. Then the double clustering standard error is given by `V = V_ent + V_time - V_white`. So you can use your PanelOLS regression to give you each of these variance estimators and then compute the double-clustering standard errors by yourself.